# Is it possible to click desktop icons behind the Flutter app (transparent windows app)

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, desktop, transparent

I wonder how to make a transparent windows app by Flutter

It normally stays background without any responses, but responds specific events such as double-click.

Let me show you what I want to make as below

[Example]

[image]

1. A transparent calendar app is running on the background and an example windows folder is visible. (see red box)

[image]

2. I can click the example folder, the calendar app ignores the click. (see red box)

[image]

3. I can drag the example folder, the calendar app ignores the drag. (see red box)

[image]

4. When I double-click the calendar cell, the app responds and the note open. (see yellow box)

[image]

The example app is desktopcal.

I want to make the same function like above example by Flutter, but have no idea.

Could tell me what widget or plugin I should find?

It will be really appreciated.